# Unresolved constructor for bitset

Tags: c++, stl, bitset

```
typedef unsigned long int  uint32;

uint32 c = uint32(-1) - 5;
std::bitset<32> y(uint32(c));
```

This code yields:

> FeatureTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class
>   std::bitset<32> __cdecl y(unsigned long)"
>   (?y@@YA?AV?$bitset@$0CA@@std@@K@Z) referenced in function _main

How can i do it for unsigned long?

EIDT: Looks like this is a bug in VS 2010 - https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532897/problems-constructing-a-bitset-from-an-unsigned-long-in-the-vc-rc

Comment: Is there something `<cstdint>` and `std::uint32_t` lacks that your not-necessarily-32-bits typedef of an `unsigned long` to `uint32` delivers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message indicates, the compiler is parsing your code as declaring a function `y`. This is an instance of the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) problem. In this particular case, you don't need a cast at all, `c` is already the right type. But if you needed a cast, you could work around it by replacing `uint32(c)` with `(uint32)c` or better `static_cast<uint32>(c)`.

Comment: I'm lost seeing why a cast/convert is needed *at all*. It's already `uint32`. Why not just `std::bit set<32> y(c);`